# How to use APC only for frontend?

Tags: cache, apc

we have recently installed an apc cache for our magento shop and it works so far.
Now we have a new module using ioncube Loader and as far as we now know these two things are not compatible.
The module only works in the backend so I hope to find  a way to deactivate apc for backend area.
But I can't find an option in the apc config to do so.
Isn't it possible to restrict the apc?

Comment: AFAIK there's no compatibility issues with APC and ionCube Loader. Have you seen any issues with both of them running side-by-side?

Comment: Unfortunately I have. We are using an importer connecting to several marketplaces and to our shop. And as soon as we activate APC the importer drives crazy and is in no condition to fullfil the job. The AOE Scheduler can finish the importer jobs and creates race conditions.

Comment: Have you considered using another OPCache like Zend instead?

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about php pecl apc module, then i think it works for real files
http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters

```
apc.filters = "-/var/www/magento/app/code/POOL/MODULE/.*"
```

or something like this. it will match every php file for that module, and exclude it from apc. never tried this honestly.

Answer (score 0):

what you are searching for is APCu, it only implements the caching without all the opcode stuff.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php

But I am pretty sure Ioncube in generell is compatible to opcache, as this is a very basic and needed Part of PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible by default. Magento's cache does not separate out the frontend and backend.

A solution would be to create a new Magento site (by symlinking the files) and create a new `app/etc/local.xml` with the values that you need. You will have to access the admin panel at a different location (like another folder or a subdomain).